# Mongodb aggregate unexpected array result - Needs to return an object from $lookup instead of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm joining two collections, but the result of trends is an array, each item always has only one trend, how do I remove the trend inside array?

'Items' collection:

```
{
 "itemid" : "370",
 "name" : "A"
},
{
"itemid" : "378",
 "name" : "B"
}
```

'Trends' collection

```
{
 "itemid" : "370",
 "max" : "715705",
},
{
 "itemid" : "378",
 "max" : "35346",
}
```

Command executed:

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
            from: "trends",
            localField: "itemid",
            foreignField: "itemid",
            as: "trend"
            }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
{
 "itemid" : "370",
 "name" : "A",
 "trend" : [       // unexpected array, the result is always a single 'trend'
        {
          "itemid" : "370",
          "max" : "715705",
        }
    ]
},
...
```

Expected:

```
{
 "itemid" : "370",
 "name" : "A",
 "trend" : {      // yeah, without array          
             "itemid" : "370",
             "max" : "715705",                    
            }
},
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an unexpected result, as `$lookup` would result in retrieving all matched documents into an array i.e; `trend` will be an array in your case. It's for a reason, Assume if you're joining `collection A` with `collection B` & documents in `collection A` might multiple matching documents in `collection B` then all those documents from `collection B` are pulled into an array of that relative document of `collection A` in your case `trend` field. Here if you wanted to get object inside it you need to do one of these ::

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
            from: "trends",
            localField: "itemid",
            foreignField: "itemid",
            as: "trend"
            }
    },
    { $addFields: { trend: {$arrayElemAt : ["$trend", 0] } } } // This stage is going re-write trend field with first object from trend array created by $lookup stage.
])
```

(*Or*)

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
            from: "trends",
            localField: "itemid",
            foreignField: "itemid",
            as: "trend"
            }
    },
     { $unwind: { path: "$trend", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } } 
])
```

**Note :** When you use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#examples) you need to be cautious that you need to use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option as if `trend` is an `[]` - which means no match found in `collection B`, then `$unwind` is going to remove all `collection A` documents with `trend :[]` in the final aggregation result.

Comment: @ViniciusRaupp : Yes it might work, but I'm giving you all the possible scenarios.If you might need all docs from `collection A` though there is no match in `collection B` i.e; `trend : []`, So here `$unwind` will remove this kind of docs. That's why we need `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true`. As `$unwind` can be tricky cause if your `aggregation` returns 100s or 1000s of documents then you might not be able to validate whether query really did work to return all docs or not. So it's better to use it rather than loose few docs :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline stage

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
            from: "trends",
            localField: "itemid",
            foreignField: "itemid",
            as: "trend"
            }
    },
    $unwind:"$trend"
])
```